# How to do regression with errors that follow one of the ARIMA-type models?

Tags: python, time-series, regression, arima, autoregressive-models

I want to model a time series with auto regressive errors.
In the statsmodel ARIMA process (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html), it is one of the uses cases. But there are no such example to showcase this process.

If someone can help me with an example code for this process.

I have tried to experiment with the different parameters of ARIMA but not been successful.

Comment: https://www.projectpro.io/article/how-to-build-arima-model-in-python/544

Comment: This is again a standard example of ARIMA process and not the specific case I am looking for. Thanks for your efforts.